# Filter field based on previous field selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

How can I use simple_form to filter a field, based on a previous fields value?

For instance, I have an Opportunities form, with two fields, Company and Contact.

Company Field:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.association :company, collection: Company.all.order(:account), prompt: "", :label_method => :account, :value_method => :id %>
  </div>
```

Contact Field:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.association :contact, collection: Contact.all.order(:first_name), prompt: "", :label_method => lambda { |contact| "#{contact.first_name} #{contact.last_name}" }, :value_method => :id %>
  </div>
```

Here is what I want to do: If I select a company called "Deviant" from the Company field above, I want the Contact field to only display those contacts associated with the company called "Deviant".

I am trying something like this, but can't get it to work:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.association :contact, collection: Contact.where("company_id = ?", params[:id]), prompt: "", :label_method => lambda { |contact| "#{contact.first_name} #{contact.last_name}" }, :value_method => :id %>
  </div>
```

I don't know how to reference the value in the Company field.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

**Update**

Anyone? Surely this must be possible. This is a key functionality in any form. I would hope I don't need jQuery or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best approach is to use ajax requests to update your contacts collection dinamically whenever the company's selected value is changed.

First you'll need an action in your contacts controller:

app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def contacts_list
    if params[:company_id]
      @contacts = Contact.where(company_id: params[:company_id])
    else
      @contacts = Contact.all
    end

    respond_with(@contacts) do |format|
      format.json { render :json => @contacts.to_json(:only => [:id, :first_name, :last_name]) }
    end        
  end
end
```

Add this to your routes:

config/routes.rb

```
  post 'contacts_list' => "contacts#contacts_list", as: :contacts_list
```

Then use the coffeescript code bellow to populate your contacts' collection:

app/assets/javasctipts/companies.js.coffee

```
$(document).ready ->
  if $("#opportunity_company_id")
    populate_contacts()
    $("#opportunity_company_id").change ->
      populate_contacts()

populate_contacts = ->
  $contacts_select = $("select#opportunity_contact_id")
  $contacts_select.attr "disabled", "disabled"
  company_id = $("select#opportunity_company_id").val()
  if company_id is ""
    $contacts_select.html "<option value=\"\">(select the company first)</option>"
  else
    $contacts_select.html "<option value=\"\">(loading contacts...)</option>"
    data = {company_id: company_id}
    data[window._auth_token_name] = window._auth_token
    $.ajax "/contacts_list",
      type: "post"
      dataType: "json"
      data: data
      success: (contacts) ->
        _html = '<option value="">Select the contact:</option>'
        _html += '<option value="'+contact.id+'">'+contact.first_name + ' ' + contact.last_name + '</option>' for contact in contacts
        $contacts_select.html _html
        $contacts_select.removeAttr "disabled"
      error: ->
        alert 'Error trying to load contacts.'
```

Finally, inside your html's head tag:

```
<% if protect_against_forgery? %>
  <script>
    window._auth_token_name = "<%= request_forgery_protection_token %>";
    window._auth_token = "<%= form_authenticity_token %>";
  </script>
<% end %>
```

Hope it helps...

*update:*
Add the following line to your ApplicationController (app/controllers/application_controller.rb):

```
respond_to :html, :xml, :json, :js
```

Comment: I am pretty close, but it gets stuck on "loading contacts...". I can see in the terminal that it appears to be doing the correct query `SELECT `contacts`.* FROM `contacts` WHERE `contacts`.`company_id` = '1'` but it won't show the data.

Comment: Hi, Meebix, I've updated the answer with an additional line to application controller and also fixed some bugs in the coffeescript code (companies.js.coffee)

Comment: Spoke a bit too soon. Doesn't work in production. It can't verify the token correctly... (Using devise)

Comment: But works in development? have you set the 'csrf_meta_tag' in your application layout file?