# How do I get multiple form elements values passed to the controller in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

`

```
<%= form_tag do %>
<p style="color:blue">Category</p>
<%= select_tag(:categorydrop, options_for_select(@categoryarr)) %>
<%= select_tag(:subcategorydrop, options_for_select(@subcategoryarr)) %>

<%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

`I have two dropdown select_tags in a form. Is there a way I can get both the values selected to the controller?
Or is there an alternate way in which I can get the two values selected to controller?

Please help

Comment: All form inputs should be passed to the controller. Without seeing your code, though, it's difficult to tell where the problem might be. Please show your view and your controller code.

Comment: @Brian Please have a look at the code in the question. I want both the values in categorydrop and subcategorydrop to be passed to the controller

Comment: Please show your controller code, as well as what is being output from your Rails console. My initial guess that that you're using strong parameters in your controller but not permitting both `categorydrop` and `subcategorydrop`.

Comment: @Brian I just realised that the above code would not solve my problem. I basically want to pass category and subcategory from drop down menus to the controller. However, I want only those subcategories to be displayed which are subcategory of the chosen category. Can you help me with this?

Comment: you will need js for that. refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180903/filter-field-based-on-previous-field-selection. Unless it's a particular code issue or blocker, I will suggest searching for the use-case before asking. Lot such questions are answered by community.